# merge two RDD where the keys are not same but related

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, rdd

In pyspark, considering the two rdds like:

`rrd1 = [('my name',5),('name is',4)]`

and

`rdd2 = [('my',6),('name',10),('is',5)]`

where rdd1 is the tuples of bigrams and counts, rdd2 is the tuples of corresponding unigram and counts,
I want to have an RDD of tuples of 3 elements like:

`RDD = [ (('my name',5),('my',6),('name',10)) ,  (('name is',4), ('name',10),('is',5)) ]`

I tried `rdd2.union(rdd1).reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x+y)` but in this case it is not the proper way because the **keys are different but** **in some sense they are related**.

Comment: Are you using python or scala? You tagged python, but your code is scala?

Comment: I'm using python, the examples are just to show an rdd in the form of a list of tuples. I don't know scala!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this; Split the *bigram* rdd to generate a key to join with `rdd2`, and then group by the bigram to collect elements belonging to the same bigram together:

```
(rdd1.flatMap(lambda x: [(w, x) for w in x[0].split()])    
     .join(rdd2.map(lambda x: (x[0], x)))
     .map(lambda x: x[1])
     .groupBy(lambda x: x[0])
     .map(lambda kv: (kv[0],) + tuple(v[1] for v in kv[1]))
     .collect())

# [(('name is', 4), ('name', 10), ('is', 5)), (('my name', 5), ('name', 10), ('my', 6))]
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can keep the order, like in the second tuple the order of ('name',10) and ('my',6) is not same as the bigram 'my name' I want to have something like 
`[(('name is', 4), ('name', 10), ('is', 5)), (('my name', 5), ('my', 6), ('name', 10))]`